# Tomcat Deploying 2 Projects

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, jakarta-ee

I have a requirement that I need to use a single server machine to run 2 totally different applications.

The server machine has Apache Tomcat 6.0 installed. 1 of the applications is deployed on it and is running successfully for a long time. Initially, the clients used to connect to it by invoking the url "http://machine-name/1stProjectName/initialPage". I have also mentioned the "initialPage" as the Welcome Page in web.xml of this project. But somehow, later some ports or relating things were changed by the server maintenance team, and to connect to the application, now one has to use the url "http://machine-name" or "http://machine-name/initialPage", i.e. the machine name has started behaving like the project name folder because now if I invoke the url "http://machine-name/1stProjectName/initialPage", it gives 404 error saying that "/1stProjectName/1stProjectName/initialPage" resource not available.

Now, when I deploy the WAR of the second application into the webapps folder of Tomcat (just like I did for the first application), it unpacks it properly. But, the issue is how do I connect to this second project. If I use "http://machine-name", it takes me to the 1st application and if I use "http://machine-name/2ndProjectName/initialPage", it gives me an error that "/1stProjectName/2ndProjectName/initialPage" not available.

Kindly help or guide me in some direction.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there an Apache HTTP server running infront of the Tomcat instance (propably using mod_jk or mod_proxy_ajp)? I think you will need to speak with the server maintenance team and find out what they changed.

Comment: Keep in mind that both apps use the same JVM. Did you test that, do you have enough memory for one JVM to host both applications?

Answer (score 3):

Your URLs should look like this if you did things properly:

1. Project 1: `http://host:port/war-name-1`
2. Project 2: `http://host:port/war-name-2`

That means no changes to content.xml to modify the path.

Answer (score 3):

I would talk to your "server maintenance team" and let them know what you are trying to do (since they are the ones who made these changes in the first place).  But it sounds to me that they just mapped a path to a specific location, that is your machine-name root is mapped to `1stProjectName`.